# Migrating DAG run history / metadata to Cloud Composer 2

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am in the middle of migrating our self managed Airflow environment to Cloud Composer 2 and was wondering how I can migrate the DAG run history from the external environment to the new Cloud Composer environment. Has anyone does this before? Is there documentation?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-database) you can find an explanation of how to access airflow database on cloud composer.

What you need to do, is migrate you self managed Airflow DB to the same version used in Cloud Composer:

```bash
airflow db upgrade -r "<current version>:<cloud composer version>"
# ex:
airflow db upgrade -r "2.0.0:2.2.0"
```

Then you can export your DB and import it in the Cloud Composer DB:

Ex for postgres DB:

```bash
# in your db
pg_dump -U <your db user> -d <your db name (airflow)> -f airflow_dump.sql
# in cloud composer db
psql -U <cloud composer db user> -d <cloud composer db name> -f airflow_dump.sql
```